# Setup postfix, help needed

Tags: postfix

My main goal is to have email sent to me via ZoneMinder.  I have a FQDN set, I have looked at many different setup instructions including [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04), and [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/install-and-configure-postfix-mail-server), as well as other tutorials that I can't list because of my reputation. Including my mail log, and setup.

I am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong if anything, or if it has to do with my ISP.

I hope I have provided plenty of information. I also have a noip account to get access outside of the LAN.

**Telnet localhost 25**

> Trying ::1...
>   Connected to localhost.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

**Telnet www.mydomain.com 25**

> Trying 69.254.72.165...
>   Connected to mydomain.com.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

**Log**

```
> Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/pickup[3146]: 6A21F9C1229: uid=1000 from=<kirt>
Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/cleanup[3178]: 6A21F9C1229: message-id=<20160620012606.6A21F9C1229@mydomain.com>
Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/qmgr[2794]: 6A21F9C1229: from=<kirt@kirthamlin.com>, size=349, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/local[3184]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/local[3184]: 6A21F9C1229: to=<user@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<kirt>, relay=local, delay=0.14, delays=0.07/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, st$
Jun 19 21:26:06 herbie postfix/qmgr[2794]: 6A21F9C1229: removed
Jun 19 21:26:11 herbie postfix/qmgr[2794]: 4BF039C0B83: from=<user@mydomain.com>, size=350, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jun 19 21:26:22 herbie postfix/smtp[3172]: connect to mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152]:25: Connection timed out
```

**postfix con**f.

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.com, herbie, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = mydomain.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up postfix is much easier with this package that ubuntu comes with.

```
sudo apt-get install mail-stack-delivery
```

Should set up everything for you - postfix and dovecot.  Just make another user on linux

```
adduser myname
```

and it will automatically set up an email for you.

Of course you have to set mx records to point to your domain